# How to install the latest compatible MacOS version?

Tags: macos, upgrade

I have a Mac Mini (Mid 2011, Core i5, 8GB RAM) running OS X Lion.

This Mac [cannot run MacOS Mojave](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP777?locale=en_GB), so I'm trying to find out:

- **which MacOS version is the last compatible with this Mac**
- **how to get the update?**

Things I tried:

- I installed all available updates in Software Update, yet I'm not proposed an upgrade to a later OS X version.
- Searching the App Store for MacOS only offers MacOS Mojave.
- Using MacOS internet recovery (Option-Command-R) installs Lion again.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks, that answers my second point! The first question is still open though: **how to find out which MacOS version is the last compatible with my Mac?**

Comment: Several methods - 1) logical extrapolation from your link. It is one year too old to run Mojave, so it can run the one before. 2) https://everymac.com 3) trial & error [not recommended ;)

Comment: Thanks, I would've expected a canonical reference from Apple, with a list of all hardware they produced and compatible Mac versions; but it looks like they're not very much interested in providing support for older hardware!

Comment: I've always thought it was one of those things you discover the hard way, when there's an update & suddenly you cant run it. I've a few Mac Pros stuck that way - one on El Cap, one at High Sierra & my main machine won't be capable of Catalina :\

Comment: They go in waves - Apple will drop certain models that can't handle one important new aspect of the next OS. High Sierra to Mojave depends on GPU spec, Metal-capable.

Comment: BTW [off topic] your user pic always intrigues me - Central line running parallel to District & Circle, then crossing the Piccadilly… makes my head hurt, can't happen ;)))

Comment: Haha I don't remember exactly, but I surely made it up! Good old times when I lived in London ;-)